# Python scp copy file with spaces in filename

Tags: python, filenames, space, scp

I'm trying to copy files in local network with scp.
It's working well with filenames without spaces, but it crash with.
I've tried to replace " " with "\ " as this [exemple](http://www.mikestechblog.com/joomla/operating-systems-section/operating-systems-ubuntu/128-scp-ambiguous-error-solved.html), but it don't work.
Here is my code:

```
def connection(locals):
         a = (int(re.search(br'(\d+)%$', locals['child'].after).group(1)))
         print a
         perc = (Decimal(a)/100)
         print (type(perc)), perc
         while gtk.events_pending():
             gtk.main_iteration()
         FileCopy.pbar.set_text("Copy of the file in the Pi...   " + str(a) + "%")
         while gtk.events_pending():
             gtk.main_iteration()
         FileCopy.pbar.set_fraction(perc)

file_pc = "/home/guillaume/folder/a very large name of file with space .smthg"
file_pi = "pi@192.168.X.X:/home/pi/folder/a very large name of file with space .smthg"

if " " in file_pc:
   file_pc = fichier_pc.replace(" ", '\\\ ')   # tried '\\ ' or '\ '
   file_pi = fichier_pi.replace(" ", '\\\ ')   # but no way
else:
   pass
command = "scp %s %s" % tuple(map(pipes.quote, [file_pc, file_pi]))
pexpect.run(command, events={r'\d+%': connection}) # this command is using to get the %
```

How can I fix this problem ?
Thanks

Comment: related: [How to escape spaces in path during scp copy in linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19858176/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may keep local file `file_pc` as is (`pipes.quote` will escape the spaces). The remote file should be changed:

```
import pipes

file_pi = 'pi@192.168.X.X:/home/pi/folder/file with space.smth'
host, colon, path = file_pi.partition(':')
assert colon
file_pi = host + colon + pipes.quote(path)
```

i.e., `user@host:/path/with space` should be changed to `user@host:'/path/with space'`

Comment: You're strong. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use `subprocess` module and/or `shlex.split()`:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['scp', file_pc, file_pi])
```

and you don't need to worry about escaping or quoting anything

Comment: No, I can't. I want to get the output of the command, to display the progressbar. (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687296/python-copy-file-in-local-network-linux-linux-and-output)

Comment: output is displayed on stdout. If you wan't it captured to react in realtime... well, it can be done, but it's a lot of hassle. You need threads, reopening fd descriptor for process stdout with proper flags etc. It would be better to check `paramiko` module, but that's completely different question.

Comment: I tried paramiko, but, there is a bug with big files (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22708942/python-paramiko-module-error-with-callback)). As I say, the script works fine with no spaces in the name.

Comment: @m.wasowski: read [my answer to the question that  Guillaume've linked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22695208/4279). It shows that `scp` prints *nothing* if stdout is a pipe. Though it works with pseudo-tty provided by `pexpect` module (there are no buffering issues in this case). The issue is how to pass filenames with spaces to scp command

Comment: Ok, I give another solution when i get home

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/), a Python library that streamlines the use of SSH.

```
from fabric.state import env
from fabric.operations import get

env.user = 'username'
env.key_filename = '/path/to/ssh-key'

get('/remote_path/*', 'local_path/')
```

Comment: `fabric` is implemented on top of [`paramiko` that breaks for large files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22708942/python-paramiko-module-error-with-callback)