# unable to download files using ftputil

Tags: python, python-3.x, download, ftputil

I am trying to download files which have been created in past 6 days, I'm able to print the names of the files but not download the files from the FTPserver to the local system. Please suggest where I'm wrong.

```
import ftplib
import ftputil
import os
import datetime

now=datetime.datetime.now()
print (now)
ago=now-datetime.timedelta(days=6)
print (ago)

class MySession(ftplib.FTP):
    def __init__(self, host, userid, password, port):
        ftplib.FTP.__init__(self)
        self.connect(host, port)
        self.login(userid, password)
ftp = ftputil.FTPHost('host', 'user', 'pwd', port=21,
                     session_factory=MySession)


dir_dest=os.chdir('C:/Python34/New folder')

for root,dirs,files in ftp.walk('Windows Triage' , topdown=True):
    for name in files:
        path=ftp.path.join(root,name)
        st=ftp.stat(path)
        ctime=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_mtime)
        if ctime>ago:
            print(name)
            for fname in name:
                fpath = ftp.path.join(root,fname)
                if ftp.path.isfile(fpath):
                    ftp.download(fpath,os.path.join(dir_dest, fname), 'b')
```

Comment: So... what happens instead?

Comment: What value do you think is bound to `fname` in `for fname in name:` in each loop iteration? Check your assumption by `print`ing it. And what's the value of `dir_dest`?

Comment: if i give print, i will get one file name per iteration, how can i specify this file to download, 'dir_dest' is the target directory where i want the files to get downloaded

Comment: Please `print` out `fname`. You won't get a _name_ per iteration then.

Comment: think about the difference `for character in "some string"` and `for s in ["some", "list"]`

Comment: unrelated: here's [code that downloads all files in a folder using `paramiko` (sftp)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20381739/4279)

Comment: hello guys, i figured it out and it is working properly. Instead of taking "fname in name", i took "name in files"